# Image in Page property in CQ5

Tags: adobe, aem

I have set an image of type .jpg in image tab of page property. How can I fetch or access this image in the component JSP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not being able to see what you have implemented I'm assuming this will save some properties to the page level based around the image such as its source.

This means you can then pull that out using

```
currentPage.getProperties().get("property","default");
```